# Text on the WPF ComboBox is not removing properly

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I am creating a WPF Application for some multipurpose things. The application contains one Combobox and is a text search enabled(auto search) one. I did the code for searching on the Combobox and it is working perfectly. The issue is coming when I type something on the Combobox and it will search for the corresponding item in the module. Once I select any item from the dropdown, the selected item is coming o the Combobox. But the text I typed also coming just above the selected item. The description is a little confusing I know, so I adding the image and the XAML for my Combobox for little more clarification.

Adding Images.
[When I search "i" in the Combobox, it shows items containing the letter "i"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5OfT.png).

[When I select item "unni", it came in the Combobox as selected item, but the text I typed is still there.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYj2r.png)

Adding the XAML for my comboBox as well.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="module" ItemsSource= "{Binding Screens}" Padding="5 2"
                 FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}" Style="{StaticResource RoundComboBox}"
                 IsTextSearchEnabled="False"
                 FontFamily="{StaticResource MontserratMedium}" Height="28" Background="#f1f1f1" 
                 BorderBrush="#f1f1f1" BorderThickness="1"  VerticalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" 
                 Width="369" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Foreground="#525252" FontSize="14" SelectionChanged="module_SelectionChanged" 
                  Margin="1,0,-1,0" PreviewTextInput="module_PreviewTextInput">
                </ComboBox>
```

The search option enabled inside the PreviewTextInput event, if required I will add the code also.
So I need a solution to remove the text I searched like in the image.

Code for PreviewTextInput event

```
 private void module_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox cmb = (ComboBox)sender;

        cmb.IsDropDownOpen = true;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cmb.Text))
        {
            string fullText = cmb.Text.Insert(GetChildOfType<TextBox>(cmb).CaretIndex, e.Text);
            //cmb.ItemsSource =
            cmb.ItemsSource = Screens.Where(s => s.IndexOf(fullText, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) != -1).ToList();
        }
        else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Text))
        {
            cmb.ItemsSource = Screens.Where(s => s.IndexOf(e.Text, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) != -1).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            cmb.ItemsSource = Screens;
        }
    }
```

Code for selection Changed

```
private void module_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!parentWindow.initDone) { return; }
            if (module.Text.Trim() != "")
            {
                MainWindow parentWindow = (MainWindow)Window.GetWindow(this);
                parentWindow.NextScreen.IsEnabled = true;
            }
           // var index = module.SelectedIndex;
            var name = module.SelectedItem;
            var index = modList.FindIndex(a => a.GivenName == name);
            if (index >= 0 && index <= (modList.Count - 1))
            {
                parentWindow.createApp.SetModule(modList[index]);
                SetModuleAndFreeze(modList[index], firstTry);
                firstTry = true;
                if (parentWindow.NextScreen.IsEnabled == false)
                {
                    parentWindow.NextScreen.IsEnabled = true;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            Logger.Instance.Error("Exception!" + ex.Message + Environment.NewLine + ex.StackTrace);
        }

    }
```

As I said, the PreviewTextInput is searching and giving value, but it happening when setting the selected Item I thing.

Comment: Can you provide code of the variable where the search text is stored?. Is it a varaible? A property? Need some more information to be able to help you.

Comment: I will add that code as well. Storing it to an Observable collection.

Comment: Can you share module_SelectionChanged and module_PreviewTextInput?

Comment: Yes, I am sharing now.

Comment: @sonu_krishna you haven't put enough code in it that I can debug it. But maybe try assign cmb.Text to "" in module_SelectionChanged.

Comment: Adding cmb.Text = "" is not working. I can't add the entire code here for some reasons.

Comment: @sonu_krishna unfortunately I can't help that much. I would by tring reset some value after choosing value. Something must store this string. When you debug, you will surely find the value you have entered.